# Compress software installers into one executable

Tags: windows-7, python, installer

How am I going to compress (I don't know what's the right term for this) different software installer into one? When I click the executable file, all the installer I have is there, then I can proceed to installing each one of them.

Comment: What platforms or OSes? This is probably more appropriate for Stack Overflow. Installer questions are on-topic there, and there are likely more folks with experience in writing them (or the scripts to build them, like Inno scripting).

Answer (score 1):

you can look into tools like [UXPacker](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) or [AdvancedInstaller](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/) to build the outer package.

That said, these tools are usually problematic as almost all antivirus systems treat these kinds of packers as suspicious if not outright dangerous. depending on the AV, it might even delete them on execute, or even prevent them from being downloaded at all.

Comment: If that's the case, is there any other way aside from this?

Comment: not without buying professional tools and a signed certificate from a Certificate Authority the OS/AV vendor recognizes.